# Scaling graphics drawing area Java Swing/awt

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

I am developing **vector graphics editor** in **Java Swing/AWT** technology.

I am curious about solution for creating drawing area (workspace), which have size bigger than users screen resolution.

For example: [Window of creating new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AHP1.png)

`public WorkspaceComponent() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(**WIDTH**,**HEIGHT**));}`

User wants to create a document of size e.g **1920 x 1080[px]**, but his/her screen has only **1280 x 720 [px]**.

Does anybody have an idea or solution for scaling the drawing area to match screen and after export having original size?

Comment: Just add the drawing area to a JScrollPane, so the user can scroll around. The problem with scaling an imager larger is that you will get pixilation.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `AffineTransform` on the `Graphics2D` Context you can scale the drawing area. Using this, you could even implement something like a zoom in/out feature.

```
double scaledSize = ... // do calculations of the scale here

AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
t.scale(scaledSize, scaledSize);
g2d.setTransform(t);

// do your drawing after setting the transform
```

If your scale is 1, it wont change the scale. A value less than one will make it smaller and a value greater than 1 will make it bigger.